# php/html with flot and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html, flot

I have issues with my javascript. Currently, I'm working on this javascript using flot to generate a graph, first by extracting data from mysql via php and then using json_encode to output the array data which will be used in the javascript. I'm not able to spot my mistake as to why my graph isn't plotting. Thanks!

```
<?php
 include ('config2.php');
 $tbl_name4 = EITMBS;
 $data = array();
  $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name4";
  $result=mysqli_query($link, $sql);
  $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  for ($nrow = 1; $nrow <= $row_cnt; $nrow=$nrow+1)
 {

  $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name4 WHERE id = '$nrow'";   
  $result=mysqli_query($link, $sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  $data[$nrow] = $row[Power];
  echo $data[1];
  echo $data[2];
 }

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Power Consumption</title>
    <link href="layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.flot.js"></script>
 </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Power Consumption</h1>

    <div id="placeholder" style="width:600px;height:300px"></div>


    <p id="hoverdata">Mouse hovers at
    (<span id="x">0</span>, <span id="y">0</span>). <span id="clickdata"></span></p>

    <p>A tooltip is easy to build with a bit of jQuery code and the
    data returned from the plot.</p>

    <p><input id="enableTooltip" type="checkbox">Enable tooltip</p>




<script type="text/javascript"> 


$(function () {
    var graph = [];
    var power = <?php echo json_encode($data);?>;


    for (var i = 1; i < 9; i += 1) {

        //alert(power[i]);
        graph([i,[power(i)]);

    }

    var plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"),
           [ { data: graph, label: "cos(x)" } ], {
               series: {
                   lines: { show: true },
                   points: { show: true }
               },
               grid: { hoverable: true, clickable: true },
               yaxis: { min: 0, max: 25 }
             });

    function showTooltip(x, y, contents) {
        $('<div id="tooltip">' + contents + '</div>').css( {
            position: 'absolute',
            display: 'none',
            top: y + 5,
            left: x + 5,
            border: '1px solid #fdd',
            padding: '2px',
            'background-color': '#fee',
            opacity: 0.80
        }).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
    }

    var previousPoint = null;
    $("#placeholder").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
        $("#x").text(pos.x.toFixed(2));
        $("#y").text(pos.y.toFixed(2));

        if ($("#enableTooltip:checked").length > 0) {
            if (item) {
                if (previousPoint != item.dataIndex) {
                    previousPoint = item.dataIndex;

                    $("#tooltip").remove();
                    var x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(2),
                        y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2);

                    showTooltip(item.pageX, item.pageY,
                                item.series.label + " of " + x + " = " + y);
                }
            }
            else {
                $("#tooltip").remove();
                previousPoint = null;            
            }
        }
    });

    $("#placeholder").bind("plotclick", function (event, pos, item) {
        if (item) {
            $("#clickdata").text("You clicked point " + item.dataIndex + " in " + item.series.label + ".");
            plot.highlight(item.series, item.datapoint);
        }
    });
});
</script> 

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried using firebug / view source here, it's pretty good at showing you what your db output is and from that it's normally obvious where the issue lies... perhaps you could at the html rendered? I would also be a bit cautious in your for loop with your select *, I am also a bit confused by your loop anyway seems a bit pointless doing the selects twice.

Comment: Can you insert this line `alert(power.toSource());` after `var power = <?php echo json_encode($data);?>;` and open up your page on firefox (or any gecko based browser), this will print out the format of the object you are storing in power.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the prompt reply. I was using alert() to prompt me what data is being output. However, my graph remains blank. What is firebug?

Comment: Hi george, I will do it now and paste the result

Comment: ({1:"21.5956108", 2:"21.58624209", 3:"21.56893068", 4:"11.02535742", 5:"21.36839694", 6:"0", 7:"21.19996992", 8:"21.17465027"})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `var power` contains an object of integers for keys and floating point numbers in string format. You may have the wrong datatype enforced in your database (for mysql looks like you should be using `FLOAT`).

If you have PHP 5.3.3+ you can use the following to ensure numbers are stored in number format  in a json encoded string:

```
json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

If not you can cycle through the array before you json encode it:

```
for ($i in $data) {
  $data[$i] = (float) $data[$i];
}
```

Secondly you are incorrectly converting the json encoded object to an array. Change:

```
graph([i,[power(i)]);
```

to:

```
graph.push([i, power[i]]);
```

Comment: Thanks george..you are awesome!